# R, R Programming, Loop Directory

Tags: r, loops, directory

Hi I am trying to loop through a directory of excel files for analysis.

My Variable is named FileToGrab which obtains the name of the excel file.

Where I have FileToGrab in bold is what I want the data frame to be named not the actual FileToGrab data frame.

Example FileToGrab = 2013ExcelSheet23

I want my Data Frame to be named 2013ExcelSheet23 and not FileToGrab.

FileToGrab = 2013ExcelSheet24

I want my Data Frame to be named 2013ExcelSheet24 and not FileToGrab.

FileToGrab = 2013ExcelSheet25

I want my Data Frame to be named 2013ExcelSheet25 and not FileToGrab.

..... and so on.

New to R sorry if this does not make sense. Thanks

```
x <- 1:50
for(i in seq(along=x))
{


FileToGrab  = gsub("(^ +)|( +$)", "",listofFile[i])
FileToGrab  = str_replace_all(string=FileToGrab, pattern=" ", repl="")

DirFileName = paste("C:\\Users\\w47593\\Desktop\\RProjects\\CallCenterProjectJuly2013\\Files\\",FileToGrab)
DirFileName = str_replace_all(string=DirFileName, pattern=" ", repl="")

file.name <- DirFileName 
sheet.name <- "Detail"
FileToGrab = str_replace_all(string=FileToGrab, pattern=".xls", repl="")


## Connect to Excel File Pull and Format Data
excel.connect <- odbcConnectExcel(DirFileName)
**FileToGrab**  <- sqlFetch(excel.connect, sheet.name, na.strings=c("","-"))
odbcClose(excel.connect)


}
```

Comment: ...I am not sure, but filenames that start with a numeric digit are likely not practical as identifiers in R; however, the function `assign()` might help you filling results into a sequence of variables whose names are settled during execution (so maybe you need something along the lines of `assign(sprintf(".Sheet.%s",FileToGrab), sqlFetch(...))`).

Answer (score 3):

You probably **don't** want to name your objects starting with numbers as you would have to quote them each time you used them

```
> 11Foo <- 1
Error: unexpected symbol in "11Foo"
> `11Foo` <- 1
> 11Foo
Error: unexpected symbol in "11Foo"
> `11Foo`
[1] 1
```

Like wise, I doubt you want 25+ objects clogging up your workspace. A far better solution is often to import the data into a list and work with those objects. You have similar issues with accessing the names

```
> ll <- list(`1` = 1, `2` = 2)
> ll$1
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "ll$1"
> ll$`1`
[1] 1
```

but then you don't need to refer to them by name necessarily, and you benefit by being able to iterate over the list using `lapply` etc.

I would use something like

```
fs <- list.file("dir/to/excel/files", glob2rx("*.xls"))
ll <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(fs))

for (i in seq_along(ll)) {
  excel.connect <- odbcConnectExcel(fs[i])
  ll[[i]] <- sqlFetch(excel.connect, sheet.name, na.strings=c("","-"))
  odbcClose(excel.connect)
}

names(ll) <- sub("\\.xls", "", fs)
```

You would still have to extract via

```
ll$"2013ExcelSheet25"
```

but you can also use

```
ll[["2013ExcelSheet25"]]
```

or better

```
ll[[1]]
```

or even

```
ll[[which(names(ll) == "2013ExcelSheet25")]]
```

But because these are all in a single list the are contained, and you can operate on them via `lapply` and co.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
files = list.files(DirFileName)
```

and then iterate through that to load them into R?

Assignment to object using filenames:

```
objects = list()
objects[[files[1]]] = ...
```

Comment: What do you want, a round of applause? I deleted my comment as soon as I noticed you had updated your Answer. Your answer is succinct, mine is closer to a full solution, with some warnings/explanations. Both will help the OP, so what's with the stupid attitude?

Comment: I wasn't poaching! I was clearly working on mine well before it was answered just by virtue of the timestamps and the length of my post. I'd effectively finished mine when your two line Answer popped up which didn't answer the actual question. In the mean time you edited your answer and I posted mine after a few additions. If I thought yours was a better Answer I'd have deleted mine (to whit http://stackoverflow.com/a/17797415/429846 where the answers were both worked on at same time, but mine offered nothing new hence I deleted it).

Comment: And if you think [so] is a race to see who answers first then you are going to be disappointed. It is about providing good answers that are broadly useful beyond helping the original OP out. Grow up!

Comment: Fair enough. Criticisms withdrawn